# Are there timers on batch which are more precise than ping?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

What other ways of setting up timers are in batch expect using ping command? Because ping isn't that reliable. Or can this be  done in vbscript in an easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What other ways are there of setting up timers in batch files?

You can use the `timeout` command in Windows 7 or 8.

> Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch
>   file.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> TIMEOUT delay [/nobreak]
>
> **Key**
>
> - `delay`  Delay in seconds (between -1 and 100000) to wait before continuing. 
>           The value -1 causes the computer to wait indefinitely for a keystroke 
>           (like the PAUSE command)
> - `/nobreak`
>           Ignore user key strokes. (Windows 7 or greater)
>
> Timeout will pause command execution for a number of seconds, after
>   which it continues without requiring a user keystroke. If the user
>   does press a key at any point, execution will resume immediately.

Source [Timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

---

#### Examples

> To pause the command processor for ten seconds, type:
>
> `timeout /t 10`
>
> To pause the command processor for 100 seconds and ignore any
>   keystroke, type:
>
> `timeout /t 100 /nobreak`
>
> To pause the command processor indefinitely until a key is pressed,
>   type:
>
> `timeout /t -1`

Source Technet [Timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891.aspx)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Answer (score 2):

**Waiting in milliseconds (using windows on-board tools)**

If waiting for multiple of seconds is too imprecise, the Windows Scripting Host can be used to run an one-line JScript which provides waiting in milliseconds.

The JScript can be called from command line or a batch file. The waiting period is passed as parameter.

```
// save this line as WaitMS.js
WScript.Sleep( WScript.Arguments( 0 ) ); 

// run WaitMS.js from batch to wait e.g. 400ms
cscript.exe /nologo WaitMS.js 400
```

---

**Waiting multiple of seconds**

You can use timeout (W7 and later):

```
timeout /t 10
```

will wait 10 seconds, you can termiante it by pressing any key.

---

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
```

will wait 10 seconds, you can terminate only by pressing ctrl + c

---

```
timeout /t -1
```

will wait eternal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pathping command to get millisecond delays as well.

```
pathping -p 150 -q 2 localhost >nul
```

There is also the choice command as well.

```
choice /t 5 /D Y >nul
```